# HTML: trying to embed youtube video

Tags: html, youtube, localhost

When I'm embedding a Youtube video into my website, the following error occurs:

> An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: 044VSn6cAs2PR3y3) 
>   [Learn More](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019?visit_id=636902126265246308-2065200121&p=player_error1&hl=en&rd=1)

[image]

My `index.html` contains the following markup snippet:

```
<div class="mu-about-us-right">
    <a id="mu-abtus-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=lWz-46NPqdk" target="youtube-video">
        <img src="assets/img/about-us.jpg" alt="img">
    </a>
</div>
```

I can't understand what is the error in my code. I have tried with some other videos as well so it's not a fault of Youtube server.

PS: I'm running my website on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try embedding the video using an iframe like so:

```
<div class="mu-about-us-right">
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lWz-46NPqdk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

You can't use an anchor tag to embed videos.

Comment: Thank you. your answer is working for me. But If I can't use an anchor tag, How can I use thumbnail in this case

Comment: Do you mean want to create a custom thumbnail for the video? By default, youtube will display the thumbnail chosen by the person who uploaded the video.

Comment: Yup I want to add custom thumbnaiL for the video

Comment: A custom thumbnail can be added on YouTube if you are the owner of the video. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding custom thumbnail into my youtube video. Thanks for help

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake anchor tag (`<a>`) is not the only problem. Video url is also incorrect. `watch?v=` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Oh! I didn't saw that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using iframe and giving the URL in popup anchor tag then, `<a class="popup-border popup-videos mt-200" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=_4EX7bMj2Ak?t=192"> <i class="fa fa-play"></i>`

make sure that you put only URL that start after =
EG. _4EX7bMj2Ak?t=192

Answer (score 1):

My browsers were blocking the embedded content until I used this extension.

---

Install

```
pip install sphinxcontrib.yt
```

conf.py

```
extensions = [
    , 'sphinxcontrib.yt'
]
```

file.rst

```
.. youtube:: bmbnPvSHcu4
```